# How to query to an existing database online with .net Graphql NuGet? (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, graphql

**My goal:** Create a Windows form app that queries via GraphQl to an existing online database.

**What I've done:**

- To simulate a graphQl server I've followed the official [graphql-node Tutorial](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/0-introduction/) till the end. So now I'm able to query from the GraphQl playground and get a response. This server runs on localhost:4000.
- I've created a windows form app in Visual Studio that queries in graphQl to an internal database containing mocked data. E.g.

My **Form.cs** class contains this code, where I execute the query onButtonClick

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var schema = Schema.For(@"
            type Jedi {
                name: String,
                side: String,
                id: ID
            }
            type Query {
                hello: String,
                jedis: [Jedi],
                jedi(id: ID): Jedi
            }", _ => { _.Types.Include<Query>(); }
        );

        var json = schema.Execute(_ =>
        {
            _.Query = "{jedis { name, side } }";
        });

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(json);

        label1.Text = json;
    }
```

After I execute the query my **Query.cs** class will recognize it and resolve the query

```
class Query
{
    [GraphQLMetadata("jedis")]
    public IEnumerable<Jedi> GetJedis()
    {
        return StarWarsDB.GetJedis();
    }
}
```

This is my Current internal DB

```
class StarWarsDB
{
    public static IEnumerable<Jedi> GetJedis()
    {
        return new List<Jedi>() {
    new Jedi(){ Id = 1, Name ="Luke", Side="Light"},
    new Jedi(){ Id = 2, Name ="Yoda", Side="Light"},
    new Jedi(){ Id = 3, Name ="Darth Vader", Side="Dark"}
};
    }
}
```

**The next step i want to do:**

Now, I've found a lot of examples online on how to query a db but they were always made internally in visual Studio. What I wanted to do is connecting to my personal DB running on my localHost for now (the one i made following the [graphql-node Tutorial](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/0-introduction/)) and query it with graphQl. Then take the JSON response and print it somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing it up a little bit. For starters you don't need to have a schema declaration on your client. 
If I understood you correctly you are using webforms, and want to acess a api service on the backend which will return you data.

So in that case you need a graphql "Client" in your webforms project, with which you "Connect" to a endpoint like your prisma api, and afterwards you only send querys or mutations to the api as a request.

Here is the link for the client, you install it as a nuget, and follow the documentation.

https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client

So in most simple terms explained, graphqlClient sends a query to => endpoint(in this case your prisma api) which gets data => from your database.

Client(query) => Api(select * datasource) => DB(SQL) => Api(returns data) => Client(deserialise) => bind to UI => see the output.

Answer (score 1):

> *GraphQL is a query language for your API, and a server-side runtime for executing queries by using a type system you define for your data. GraphQL isn't tied to any specific database or storage engine and is instead backed by your existing code and data.* - [**graphql.org**](https://graphql.org/learn/)

Hi Zayed

Maybe I misunderstand your explanation but you **cannot** query directly to the database using GraphQL. You'll need an API project between your connection and the GraphQL logic. You'll post your GraphQL scheme to the API endpoint and it will return, based on your endpoint, the correct data structure.

I found a [good website](https://fullstackmark.com/post/17/building-a-graphql-api-with-aspnet-core-2-and-entity-framework-core) where it will be explained step by step on how to implement it in ASP.NET CORE 2.

Hope this helps.Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand what your point is and the link seems interesting. But think of it now I already built that kind of system following [this](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/0-introduction/). The database is in Prisma, i can query him using the GraphQl Playground (localhost:4000) and using Node I resolve the query. The point is if I can connect to my localhost:4000 (from e.g. a windows form onbuttonclick or whatever) and some how pass the query string to execute. Sorry if it seems somehow confusing, maybe I'm just missing how the bigger picture works.

Comment: Prisma isn't a database. It's basically an API layer between your program and the database it queries to, but from a 3rd party instead of your own. I would recommend using your own Web API following the guide in the link above. If you still wish to use Prisma, you basically can do a HTTP request to your endpoint (the same way you're doing with Postman) and send in the scheme as the body.